# What’s the usual way in Dart to check if a list is sorted?

Tags: sorting, dart

Is there a function in the Dart standard library that allows me to check if a list is sorted or not?

Of course, I could easily implement mine (in different ways), but since this may be a recurrently needed operation, it may be useful to have such a function either as part of the `List` API or as a top-level function or algorithm in some other library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is nothing in the standard libraries.

Answer (score 4):

With the `collection` package (which is included in Flutter), you can use the `isSorted` function.

Example for checking whether a list of ints is sorted:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; 

final list = [1, 2, 3];
list.isSorted((a, b) => a.compareTo(b)); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no method that directly checks for being sorted, and it's not easily built from, say, `Iterable.fold` or `Iterable.reduce`.
It's not a feature that has been requested before, so it's unlikely to be something that is put into the platform libraries.
It might be worth putting it in a package like `package:collection` or `package:quiver`.

Here is a function you can use:

```dart
bool isSorted<T>(List<T> list, [int Function(T, T)? compare]) {
  if (list.length < 2) return true;
  compare ??= (T a, T b) => (a as Comparable<T>).compareTo(b);
  T prev = list.first;
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    T next = list[i];
    if (compare(prev, next) > 0) return false;
    prev = next;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Now its included in `package:collection` https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableComparableExtension/isSorted.html